# QML - Embedded QLineEdit - editingFinished only raised by hitting Enterkey

Tags: qml, signals-slots, qlineedit

I have a standard QLineEdit that is embedded in a QGraphicsProxyWidget, in a sperate wrapperclass, to make it accessible in QML. In my wrapperclass i make a reconnect of the signal "editingFinished" and the signal goes to the QML-Environment. In my QML-Environment there is the slot that handles this signal and prints, for the first, some text out.

When I edit the text of my LineEdit and hit enter, the signal gets emitted and the slot gets this signal and print out this message. This indicates that the signal and the slot are connected correctly. But when I edit the text and click on another Element in my QML.Environment, no signal is emitted.

What can I make to get this signal emitted. Is there an error in the focus-handling in QML?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

well, it looks like it's a problem from QML, as in the doc it says

> When editing is finished, either because the line edit lost focus or
>   Return/Enter is pressed the editingFinished() signal is emitted.

but i dont have much experience.
but it also says

> Note that if there is a validator set on the line edit, the returnPressed()/editingFinished() signals will only be emitted if the validator returns QValidator::Acceptable.